# Where do you classify this sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions, clauses, qualifiers

Once I was confused as to which version I should choose in the following sentence.

```
Any person (comes/coming) late (is) not admitted
```

It turned out that coming is the right choice. However, I still would like to know which grammar topic deals with this kind of sentences/constructions.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not really a matter of "what grammar is involved here?" It's like the sign on (for example) a nightclub door [Unaccompanied females not admitted](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unaccompanied+females+not+admitted%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Or newspaper headlines, come to that. They're only interested in conveying the message/grabbing your attention in the smallest number of words possible. Grammar is *not* a consideration.

Comment: ...having said that, your example looks unusual/non-standard to me. Normally it's [***Latecomers** not admitted*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22latecomers+not+admitted%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the examples. However, being a non native speaker, how would I know that coming/arriving is correct while comes/arrives is not in sentences like: `Anyone (arriving) after the start of the play is not allowed in until the interval`. Admittedly, the previous example was made up but thought it could make the point without having to look for the latter one. Native speakers resort to "it sounds right/natural/awkward", but what about foreigners?

Comment: To repeat what I said before, there isn't really any concept of "grammar" or "correct English" in things like signs and newspaper headlines, so I don't think they're suitable subjects for ELL. On the other hand, it's quite reasonable to ask what (if any) difference there is between *Anyone **arriving** after the start of the play **is not** allowed in until the interval* and the same sentence using ***who arrives*** and/or ***will not be*** instead (imho, the short answer is "None"). Just don't ask for an analysis of the "cut-down" usages in signs, because it's often *very* non-standard.

Comment: Technically, grammar does play a role.  We can tell this because the sign is unlikely to say "admitted not females unaccompanied".  As you can see, the word order isn't entirely random, and the words are in fact combining in a way that can be described by a grammar--something that might be of interest to a few linguists.  But it's not Standard English grammar, and (in my opinion) there's not a lot of use in describing the specialized grammar of signs to English language learners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, we could use the verb form with an -*s*, instead of the -*ing* form, if we add the word *who*:

> **Anyone arriving** after the start of the performance will not be admitted until the intermission.
>
> **Anyone who arrives** after the start of the performance will not be admitted until the intermission.
>
> **Everyone signing up** before the deadline will receive a free t-shirt.
>
> **Everyone who signs up** before the deadline will receive a free t-shirt.

I can see where this would be confusing, though, because that's not always the case with plural pronouns:

> **Everyone eats** cake for their birthday.
> **Not everyone sees** the forest through the trees.

The key is that the sentence is really structured like this:

> Everyone .. does something.

and we are dealing with some qualifying clause between those two sentence parts.

For example:

> Everyone .. will dance the chicken dance.

becomes either:

> Everyone **who attends** the wedding reception will do the chicken dance.

or:

> Everyone **attending** the wedding will do the chicken dance.

One more example:

> **Nobody** *sitting in the family section* **is allowed to drink alcohol**.
> **Nobody** *who sits in the family section* **is allowed to drink alcohol**.

Comment: Excellent! +1 The keyword here is "**qualifying** clause"

Comment: A quick Google search shows that it is called "**[restrictive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Restrictive+clause+(in+English))** clause"

Answer (score 1):

> Any person (comes/coming) late (is) not admitted

More simply:

Coming late is not admitted.

The part "coming late" is a gerund and the subject of the sentence. As to "is" in your sentence, you might want to look up subject-verb agreement.

Comment: "Coming late is not admitted" by itself sounds wrong to me. "Coming late is not permitted" would be fine.

Comment: That's because *admit* here means ["to allow to enter; let in"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/admit), and you can't allow an abstract concept ("coming late") to enter, only a person.

Comment: +2! (That's because admit here means "to allow to enter; let in", and you can't allow an abstract concept ("coming late") to enter, only a person") = Great. Forgot the diff but not anymore.